# Opening files found from os.listdir() and perform tasks to files

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, directory, pipe

so I want to open each file in a directory (there are 4 plain text documents in this directory ). And do something like find specific words and its number of occurrence in each file.

This is code I used, but I got error of no such file or directory, but i when print the path, it clearly shows each file's name.

```
import re
import os

path = 'C:\\Python27\\projects\\Alabama\\New folder'

pattern = re.compile(r"\bmay not\b",re.IGNORECASE)
pattern1 = re.compile(r"\bshall\b",re.IGNORECASE)
pattern2 = re.compile(r"\bmust\b",re.IGNORECASE)
pattern3 = re.compile(r"\bprohibited\b",re.IGNORECASE)
pattern4 = re.compile(r"\brequired\b",re.IGNORECASE)

for filenames in os.listdir(path):
 with open(filenames) as myfile:
    total = 0
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0
    total3 = 0
    total4 = 0
    for line in myfile:
        m = re.findall(pattern, line)
        m1 = re.findall(pattern1, line)
        m2 = re.findall(pattern2, line)
        m3 = re.findall(pattern3, line)
        m4 = re.findall(pattern4, line)
        total += len(m)
        total1 += len(m1)
        total2 += len(m2)
        total3 += len(m3)
        total4 += len(m4)
    print total, total1, total2, total3, total4
```

my question is: how to perform the task mentioned above, to find number of word occurrence of specific words("shall""must", etc) for each documents separately in the directory?

Comment: Add the path in front of filenames in the open statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listdir` returns only the file names. You have to append the path back to the file names in order to open them.

```
for filenames in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filenames)) as myfile:
```

As for counting the words, you have several options, depending on how exactly you wish to count and what you define an "occurance" to be. For example, you can read the whole file as a string, then use `str.count` method to count only the occurances of specific words.

```
for filenames in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filenames)) as myfile:
        content = myfile.read().lower()  # to essentially ignore the case
        shall_count = content.count('shall')
```

Comment: thank you! I definitely hard coded the rest。

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation